# RMSProp Momentum and Decay

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent

I'm making an application of MobileNetV2 and according to [their article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04381.pdf):

> We train our models using
> TensorFlow. We use the standard RMSPropOptimizer with **both decay and momentum set to 0.9**.
> We use batch normalization after every layer, and the
> standard weight decay is set to 0.00004. Following
> MobileNetV1 setup we use initial learning rate of
> 0.045, and learning rate decay rate of 0.98 per epoch.
> We use 16 GPU asynchronous workers, and a batch size
> of 96.

Now, according to my research, RMSProp divides the gradient by *the square root of the moving average of squared gradients*. Like so:

$$ E_{t} = \alpha E_{t-1} + (1 - \beta) \cdot \left (\frac{\partial L}{\partial P} \right) ^2 $$

$$ P_{t} = P_{t-1} - \frac{\eta }{\sqrt{E_{t}}} \cdot \frac{\partial L}{\partial P} $$

Where $\frac{\partial L}{\partial P}$ is the gradient of a generic parameter (impact of the parameter on loss function), $\eta$ is the learning rate (which also has a decay per epoch) and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are... Well this is my question.

I named them $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for convenience's sake, but most places I found these values they are the same and both called $\rho$. Now, according to [Keras' official page on RMSProp](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/rmsprop/), *rho* and *momentum* are different variables, with *rho* signifying some sort of decay. There's also an *Epsilon* variable and I'm not sure where that falls in this equation, I only know of an $\epsilon$ for Softmax.

So my question is: In that $E_{t}$ formula, are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the momentum and decay ($\rho$ in Keras), respectively, or is the $\rho$ from Keras referring to something different?

Also, if possible, what is the *Epsilon* in the Keras definition of RMSProp? Does it fall somewhere in this formula?